# jpa manytomany how to add duplicate item

Tags: java, jpa, duplicates

I have an Entity user, and another Entity book, the user can have many books and the book can have many owner, so it is a manytomany relationship.
and a middle table user_book was created with user_id, and book_id

but now comes the problem, what happened if a user have 2 exactly same books, for example he bought the same book twice. then the primary key constraint was triggered and I can't persist the user any more.

so what can I do with it? How can a user have 2 same books?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I have figured out the way, change the Set to list, this will remove the primary key from the middle table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in this case, that you should add an identifiant field to the middle table `USER_BOOK`. This way, whenever a user takes the same book more than one time, il will be persisted simply with a new identifiant in the joined table.

Answer (score 0):

as a simple answer Never use your business key as an id! :)

as an example if you set ISBN as a Database ID of your Book entity you probably gonna have problem. however if you set book id, an arbitrary id (AutoGenerate, SequenceTable, etc) never need to worry about having same book in a relation ;)